# How to make infinite threaded comments

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

My current code allows me to render a queryset of `Comments` (parent comments) as well as replies to those comments. But i'm unable to render replies to those replies. My goal is to have an infinite reply system. Here's my code:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    destination = models.CharField(default='1', max_length=12, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='replies', related_query_name='replies', blank=True, null=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    children = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.comment_text)
```

my parent comment view:

```
def user_comment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        comment_length = len(str(ajax_comment))
        if comment.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, destination=id, user=request.user)
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length,
                                 'username': username, 'id': comment.id})
        else:
            return HttpResponse()
```

and my reply view:

```
def comment_reply(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        reply_text = request.POST.get('reply_text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        parent = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
        parent.children += 1
        parent.save()
        if comment.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=reply_text, destination=id, user=request.user, parent_id=parent_id, parent_comment=parent)
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'reply_text': reply_text, 'username': username})
        else:
            return HttpResponse()
```

ajax calls

```
var str = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
var path = str.split("/")[4];

$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var c = $(this).find('.comment_text').val()
    console.log('this:', c);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/user_comment/',
    data: {
        text: $(this).find('.comment_text').val(),
        id: path,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
},
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.text == '') {
            console.log('Cannot submit blank comment');
        } else {
            //console.log('')
            $('.commentsContainer hr').prepend("<div class='comment_div'><div class='left_comment_div'>" +
                "<div class='username_and_votes'><h3><a class='username_foreign'>" + data.username +
                "</a></h3></div><br><p>" + data.text +
                "</p></div></div>");
        }}

});

});

// reply comment

    $(document).on('submit', '.reply_comment_form', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        parent_id = $('.reply_comment_form').data('comment_id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/comment_reply/',
            data: {
                reply_text: $(this).find('.comment_text').val(),
                parent_id: parent_id,
                id: path,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.reply_comment_form').replaceWith("<div class='comment_div new_comment' style='display: inline-block;'><div class='left_comment_div'>" +
                "<div class='username_and_votes'><h3><a href='#' class='username_foreign'>" + data.username +
                "</a></h3><br><p>" + data.reply_text +
                "</p></div></div>");

            }

        });


    });
```

and the comments html

```
<div class="commentsContainer">

    <form action="" class="comment_form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment.comment_text|add_class:"comment_text" }}
        {{ comment.id }}

        <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="comment_submit">
    </form>
    <hr>
    {% for i in comment_list %}
        <div class='comment_div' data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">
            <div class="left_comment_div">
                <div class="username_and_votes">
                    <h3><a class='username_foreign'>{{ i.user }}</a></h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% for reply in i.replies.all %}
            <div class='comment_div new_comment' data-comment_id="{{ reply.id }}">
            <div class="left_comment_div">
                <div class="username_and_votes">
                    <h3><a class='username_foreign'>{{ reply.user }}</a></h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>{{ reply.comment_text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If someone could give me advice how to implement endless replies from the code I currently have that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn your comments loop into a separate template

```
{% for i in comments %}
    <div class='comment_div' data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">
        <div class="left_comment_div">
            <div class="username_and_votes">
                <h3><a class='username_foreign'>{{ i.user }}</a></h3>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'comments_template.html' with comments=i.replies.all %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then you just call this where you need it with

```
{% include 'comments_template.html' with comments=comment_list %}
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code is working there? The html I posted is already in its own template (`comments.html`).

Comment: @zorgan - it recursively calls a snippet as required

Comment: So the html I posted is in a `comments.html` template. Are you saying I should make another seperate template for my comments loop? Also I'm still very confused how `{% include 'comments_template.html' with comments=comment_list %}` is working. How is this solving the problem of infinite replies exactly?

Comment: If you had a bit of python code that you needed to use recursively you'd seperate it into a separate function. This is no different, this *section* of the comments.html you require you use more than once