# display hierarchy in django

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django to store and display the hierarchy of an organisation. I am struck with displaying the hierarchy of an organisation. 
   
For example:

- Priya  *(CEO)*
  - Harry  *(Manager)*
    - Rekha  *(Tester)*

I was able store the hierarchy using a single model and referencing to itself as below:

```
class Emp(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
manager=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
designation=models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

I had an idea to display detail view of each employee when the employee name is clicked but I don't know how to write a view for this and render it to the webpage. Is there a way to directly the hierarchy without using detail view ? Could someone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make infinite threaded comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341887/how-to-make-infinite-threaded-comments)

Comment: ^Different use case, but the answer is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using django-mptt - no need to reinvent the wheel. You'll find everything at https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt